# Force to Logout user already logged once into Blazor Web Server site on every new visit to the webpage

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, blazor-server-side

I am sorry if this is a silly question and most of all sorry for my bad english. I am still learning little bit everyday of Blazor Web server and I am little struggle on one thing and not know if I am just wasting time on trying to understand it. I am trying to implement a login logout feature on my site with custom authentication and use of custom cookie, the users can log in log out and cookie being created in the right way with some expiration time too. But let's say I close my website and all pages and then I decide to reload the page, because the cookie is not yet expired I can enter the secured pages without even need to login again. That's not what I would like to, I would like to do a check if the user first load let's say index, then it will be forced to logout. Thank you to everyone that will clarify my doubt.

I did try to implement a class for check the first occurrance of the oninitialize on the index page but I guess I did it in the wrong way.

Edit: Maybe is more easy to just logout user currently logged after all web pages closed in the client browser ?

Edit for more details:
I am a very beginner in Blazor and generally web development, so yeah all the stuff about cookie and sessions are kinda new to me. I had to do something little ugly like via IJSRuntime calling funtion during the first render of the index page, the function in my controller execute logout first and everytime user come back to the index page it get automatically logged out. I only need user to login only for special purpouse like Admin pages and some special operations that can be done only by certain users with certain rules, the rest of the website can be used without any kind of login procedure.

Comment: I think this question is not Blazor related. Probably you just need to create a session cookie. Session cookies expire once you close the browser. The cookie has to be created without Expires value. 
Exemple of code : httpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("SessionGuid", aGuid, new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieOptions { Secure = httpContext.Request.IsHttps, HttpOnly = true, Path = "/", SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax });

Comment: Hi Paul yeah I know how to create Session cookie but my question was that if is possible to force user to logout at the beginning, or even better when closed all the site pages if possible

Answer (score 0):

> I close my website and all pages and then I decide to reload the page,
> because the cookie is not yet expired I can enter the secured pages
> without even need to login again. That's not what I would like to
>
> Maybe is more easy to just logout user currently logged after all web
> pages closed in the client browser

It would great if you could share your current implementation details- what you are up to now along with the scernaio that would be great to answer or explain'

According to your scenario and requirement, you can use the "clearing the authentication cookie on page load" approach. This ensures logout immediately upon accessing the `Index.razor` page.

However,  this isn't directly achievable within Blazor Server due to its server-side rendering and SignalR connection model. The server cannot reliably detect when the client closes all tabs/windows.

But you could try few alternative ways was well. For instacnce- you can simulate this behavior by setting a very short cookie expiration time (seconds or minutes). This effectively logs out users after a brief period of inactivity.

Another way could be, Implement a server-side idle timeout mechanism that automatically invalidates the authentication cookie after a specified period of inactivity. This requires additional server-side logic and configuration.

**Note:** Keep in mind this not the exact solution of your scenario as its not clear hows your implementation looks like. But yeah, you consider this way to proceed further. In addition, please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/scenario-web-app-sign-user-sign-in?tabs=aspnetcore) that might be helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you for the good ideas you gave me, I made an edit with some more details on what I come up to,  probably this is what you mean by "clearing the authentication cookie on page load" right ?

Comment: Yeah, right you are, because in blazor server app, client stuff not directly detected so this you can try.